# iOS: Array subscript is not integer

Tags: ios, objective-c

im trying to create a basic app that has a falling image from the top. I however seem to be getting this problem:

```
Array subscript is not integer
```

on this line in my .m:

```
image.center = CGPointMake[image.center.x+pos.x, image.center.y+pos.y];
```

Here is my complete .m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)Start {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.10)
         target: self
         selector:@selector(onTimer)
         userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)onTimer {

    image.center = CGPointMake[image.center.x+pos.x, image.center.y+pos.y];
    pos = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.17);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and my .h file is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    CGPoint pos;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
    NSTimer *timer;
}

-(IBAction)Start;

@end
```

Also, can you tell me how to make the image appear and fall in random locations in the app?

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 because this sort of thing can be confusing as heck at times, so you shouldn't be penalized forit.  The way you need to approach this is to ask yourself "Why is it saying 'array subscript' when it's just method parameters?" and then look for some reason why the compiler thinks there's an array subscript operation going on.  After staring blankly at it for about 5 minutes you slap your head and say "Of course!"  Always look for the clues in the message -- something that is out of place or inconsistent with what you think it should be.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to iOS Programming and have been working on this for a very long time, very tired now. But thank you so much for the help. Its great to now that no matter what my basic skills are there are always people who genuinely love helping.

Comment: @DannyBios Here's a suggestion from a long time developer - take a break once in a while. If you get stuck on something for a while, leave it for a bit. Take a nap, eat a snack, go for a walk, whatever. Give the brain a change of scenery. Then come back to the problem. You'll be surprised how such a break can help. And don't forget some basic C and Objective-C tutorials. Enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `[` with `(` and `]` with `)`

in

`CGPointMake[image.center.x+pos.x, image.center.y+pos.y];`

because

`CGPointMake` is a function and a function call `CGPointMake(...)` always uses parentheses and not brackets.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to tell me how I can make the image fall from random locations? would it involve using arc4random() ?

Comment: @DannyBios Probably but try to google first, then ask questions.

Comment: I did, thats how I got arc4random(). I used: int x = arc4random() % (int) self.view.frame.size.height; but it just made it appear in lots of different locations all over the screen as it was coming down not start from a different location at the top. if that makes sense?

Comment: @DannyBios You should rather ask a different question, comments are too limited for this. However what you need is an initial position , which should be random, and then every step should move the position by a value (constant value for a "fall" with constant speed, increasing value for an accelerated fall). You will have to figure it by yourself or you will never learn. Just try to understand why your code does what it does.

Answer (score 0):

CGPointMake is a C function.

It takes 2 CGFloats as parameters, and returns a CGPoint.

The syntax for calling a C function is

```
result = function(param, param);
```

The function name should be followed by an open parenthesis, and comma-delimited list of 0 or more parameters, and a closing parenthesis.

As others have already pointed out, you were using square brackets instead of parentheses.